# Installing R failed

Tags: warning-messages, rlink

To install R, I evaluated the following code

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.1"]
```

and I got the follow error messages:

> Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: com.wolfram.jlink.InvalidClassException: Invalid class specification. This class is not loaded into the current Java runtime. It might have been loaded into a different Java runtime, or Java might have been restarted since the class was loaded.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Java::excptn will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. The following error was encountered: crash in low-level RLink component or in R runtime

Please help!

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1807709).